# Calling a web service through the acitviti Api?

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

I am trying to call an web service from a human task list. In Activiti API is it possible to call a web service task? Is this implemented?

In a scenario of claims approval if the second step to an approval is invoking a web service, is this possible through acitviti?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You would model it with a user task followed by either a webservice task (http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnWebserviceTask) or a java delegate (http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnJavaServiceTask) in which you could implement the webservice-call yourself.